# Adding Captcha to a Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, captcha

I am trying to implement a simple math-based captcha to my e-mail forms. (I know, math isn't fool-proof, but it will work for what I need).

I've tried numerous different attempts through tutorials and I can't seem to get it, so I figured I'd post my code up and see what comes back.

The current form:

TOP OF THE HTML PAGE -

```
<?php

/* validation function for when they press the submit button */
function validateFields($fields, $form_vars) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach($fields as $field_name => $error_msg) {
    $value_entered = trim(@$form_vars[$field_name]);
    if(empty($value_entered)) {
        $errors[$field_name] = $error_msg;
    }
}
return $errors;
}

function safe($str) { return htmlentities(strip_tags($str)); }

?>
```

The next relevant piece of code in the HTML page is Javascript:

```
<!--Form Validation Starts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/productFormValidation.js"></script>
<!--Form Validation Ends -->
```

The next relevant piece of code in the HTML page is the form itself:

```
<!-- INDIVIDUAL CONTACT LINK -->
<div class="contact_links">
<form name="contact" method="post" action="/sendmail/send-mail-start.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">


                            <label>Name: (required) </label><input class="input1" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" />


                            <label>Email: (required) </label><input class="input1" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" /><br />


                            <label>Phone: (required) </label><input class="input1" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value="" />
                            <label>Company: (required)  </label><textarea class="input2" name="comments" id="comments" cols="" rows="1"></textarea><br />
                            <input type="image" src="images/individualProducts/submit.png" alt="" value="" class="submit" />


                            </form>  

<!-- INDIVIDUAL CONTACT LINK ENDS --></div>
```

Here is the content of my productFormValidation.js file:

```
// JavaScript Document

function checkForm(formName)

{

    //NAME VALIDATION

    if(formName.name.value== "")

    {

        alert ('Please Enter Your Full Name!');

        formName.name.focus();

        return false;

    }



//EMAIL VALIDATION

if(formName.email.value=="")

{

    alert ('Please Enter Your Email!');

    formName.email.focus();

    return false;

}

//EMAIL FORMAT VALIDATON

if (!formName.email.value.match(/^[\w\.-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,}\.[a-z]{2,9}$/))

{

    alert ('Please Enter a Valid Email!');

    formName.email.select();

    return false;

}









return true;



}









// JavaScript Document

function checkForm(comment)

{

    //NAME VALIDATION

    if(comment.name.value=="")

{

    alert ('Please Enter Your Full Name!');

    comment.name.focus();

    return false;

}



//EMAIL VALIDATION

if(comment.email.value=="")

{

    alert ('Please Enter Your Email!');

    comment.email.focus();

    return false;

}

//EMAIL FORMAT VALIDATON

if (!comment.email.value.match(/^[\w\.-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,}\.[a-z]{2,9}$/))

{

    alert ('Please Enter a Valid Email!');

    formName.email.select();

    return false;

}











return true;



}
```

And finally, the code for the "ACTION" PHP file that is called in the form section:

```
<?php

    $date1=date("F d,Y");

    $nameField=$_POST['name'];
    $companyField=$_POST['company'];
    $countryField=$_POST['country'];
    $stateField=$_POST['state'];
    $emailField=$_POST['email'];
    $phoneField=$_POST['phone'];
    $urlField=$_POST['url'];



    $messageField=nl2br($_POST['comments']);


    $body="
    <table width='450' border='1px' bordercolor='#B6B6B6' align='center'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border:1px solid #B6B6B6; border-collapse:collapse; background-color:#FFF; margin-top:16px; margin-bottom:10px;'>
         <tr>
         <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center; background-color:#67a23b; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; padding:6px;''>Contact Form - SmartStart&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[&nbsp;$date1&nbsp;]</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'>Name:</td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$nameField</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'></td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$companyField</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'>Email:</td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$emailField</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'></td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$countryField</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'>Phone:</td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$phoneField</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'></td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$stateField</td>
         </tr>


          <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'>Company:</td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$messageField</td>
         </tr>


         <tr>
             <td width='150' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#6D6D6D; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f7f7f7; padding:6px;'></td>
             <td width='300' align='left' valign='top' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000; font-weight:normal; padding:6px;'>$urlField</td>
         </tr>


         </table>";

   //$from=$firstNameField;
   $sub="Contact Form - From the Smart Page".$titleField;

   $name=$firstNameField."< ".$emailField." >";
   $to="info@mycompany.com";

    if (mail($to,$sub,$body,"From:".$name."\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"))
    {
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=/smart.php\">";
    }
    else{
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.php\">";
    }

?>




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>

body {
    background-color: #636362;
    text-align: center;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#thank-you-page {
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#thank-you-page h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

#thank-you-page p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Thank-you for Contacting My Company</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="thank-you-page">
<h1>Thank-you for contacting<br />
<strong>My Company</strong></h1>
<p>Your message has been sent successfully. We will contact you shortly.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure it is simple, but everything I try throws back errors at me. How can I simply add another text-box that would ask random addition or subtraction questions - and verify the response in the same manner it verifies the e-mail etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to add the captcha after the user clicks submit?

Comment: No - I'd just like to have a simple, randomly generated "2+2=" captcha that would prevent bots from sending spam. I'd assume it would be placed just before the submit button?

Comment: Have you had any experience with jQuery? I like jQuery for this type of thing. I will throw together a fiddle with a simple captcha check. the other thing to consider is a captcha should be validated server side. anyone can turn javascript off and get by your validation. In you php i would add data validation as well. test your post vars to check if they are empty or malicious code.